# App indexing on iOS: How is Firebase App Indexing different from Mark Up Web Content

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, corespotlight, google-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

I was reading about app indexing for iOS, First thing I found was [Firebase App Indexin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/ios/app)g, which is pretty straight forward. Then I came across [Mark Up Web Content](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/WebContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH8-SW1), how is this different from Google's. If I have to do app indexing for my app should I implement both or which one to choose and how to choose?

Answer (score 1):

Great question. **Firebase App Indexing** is the renamed successor to **Google App Indexing**. This is the method Google uses to help show app content in Google search results. In theory, Apple's **Mark Up Web Content** feature is used to show web content in Spotlight searches on iOS devices. I say 'in theory' because I've never actually seen it work in practice.

Both are nice concepts that don't really seem to be fully implemented yet. At [Branch.io](https://branch.io) we support both for our partners out of the box, but we haven't seen a huge amount of traffic coming through from either one.